# replace href and url by the <c:url /> tag

Tags: regex, eclipse, notepad++

I'm working on a web application using JSP and JSTL in presentation layer.
When I get html from designer, my jsp file is updated as below:

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/fo/inc-css/normalize.css"/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/fo/inc-css/font.css"/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inc-css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inc-css/csspie.css" />
...
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="inc-js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="inc-js/plugins/jquery.fitvids.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="inc-js/plugins/jquery.bxslider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<h1><a href="/" title="Home Page">Home Page</a></h1>
...
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="LOG OUT">Log out</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="My Profile">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Help">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

There is many href/url without `<c:url />`(I don't show the whole file because it is very long). I want to replace all href/url with the `<c:url />` tag but `#`, `/` and full url. For example

```
href="inc-css/jquery.jscrollpane.css"
```

should become

```
href="<c:url value="/fo/inc-css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />"
```

Can anyone suggest me some patterns for searching/replacing in Notepad++ or Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++:

You could use this in find:

```
href="([^"<]{2,}")
```

And in replace, you can use:

```
href="<c:url value="/fo/\1 />"
                        ^^
```

The `^^` indicate where the captured group is being inserted.

EDIT: To match both `href` and `src`, you will use this:

```
(href|src)="([^"<]{2,}")
```

And replace:

```
\1="<c:url value="/fo/\2 />"
```

Comment: Thank Jerry, but your pattern matches `href="#"` as well! (I don't want to replace this href)

Comment: Thank Jerry for quickly comment. It work well except for the case `href="/"`

Comment: @TuanDang Hmm, well, I guess just so you avoid those one character long 'href', it might be better use `href="([^"<]{2,}")` instead.

Comment: Thank so much! It solved 99% problem! (except full url `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"`)

Comment: @TuanDang Oh, you need to replace the `src`s too? xD Sorry, I didn't understand that part. Added it to my answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you could

Find `href="([^#][^\"]+)"`

Replace with `href="<c:url value="$1" />"`

Although I think because you have quotes within quotes, you may be better off doing

Replace with `href="<c:url value='$1' />"`

Comment: Thank Nate, but your pattern matches `href="#"` as well!

Comment: your new pattern `href="([^#][^\"]+)"` matches `href="<c:url value="` now :D

Comment: You can add a negated character in the second position, similarly to what @Jerry said in his comment. href="([^#][^:][^\"]+)"